# HDD vanished after wakeup from standby

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, standby

In my computer I got two hard drives:
One 80GB Intel X25 Postville SSD for the system and a 1,5TB Sata HDD for data.

When I put the system into standby, and wake it up again, roundabout 50% of the time the 1,5TB HDD is not found. It just vanished from the system (wreaking havok to all programs running which had open files on it).

Even going into the system management and refreshing the drives does not find the lost HDD.

There are no messages about this in the event log.

After a warm reboot the hdd is found again, just like it should.

The system is a Shuttle SP35P2 Pro with 8GB Ram and DualCore CPU, OS is Windows 7 Ultimate. I even set up the OS anew, didn't help.

Any ideas what might cause this? How to debug, or maybe even fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problems, but with XP. This helped me ...

http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-xp/69991-standby-s3-problem-parallel-ide-hdd-missing-resume.html